# Values being sent over AJAX but not found in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a input field which when selected opens a date range calendar.

[image]

I am trying to send the date values over AJAX to a PHP file to echo when the apply button is pressed. The AJAX post request does send, however when I try to test for detection in my PHP file nothing is returned.

I have searched online and have found nothing to indicate why. Here is my code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="daterangepicker.css" /> </head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" id="dates" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
                "showDropdowns": true
                , "minDate": "01/01/2014"
            });

            $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
            });
            $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $(this).val('');
            });

            $(".applyBtn").attr('id', 'testing');

            $('#testing').click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: {
                        dates: $('#dates').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success")
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['dates'])) {
       $range = $_POST['dates'];
       echo $range;
   } else {
       echo "false";
   }
?>
```

EDIT//

response body

[image]

Comment: What is returned in actual request? You don't show any debugging code or given us much information to work from. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is actually sent and returned

Comment: _"nothing is returned"_ do you mean your `alert()` never gets executed, or that you have looked at the request in the network tab and it had nothing in the response body?

Comment: No the alert is successful and the data is sent in the response body, I just want to send the values to the php file and echo it out

Comment: Add dataType: "json", in your AJAX and in the backend replace echo with var_dump($_POST['dates']) or better var_dump($_REQUEST) and see what is returned

Comment: I removed the if statement and just put var_dump($_REQUEST) between php tags, it returned array(0) { }.

Comment: In your success method did you try alert/console.log `data`?

Comment: Yes i tried, it logs the date 07/01/2016 - 09/02/2016

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to test.php and then have the values displayed there on a blank page?

Comment: Yes however without the redirect, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, the server response is in the "Response" tab:

[image]

instead of showing "success" in the alert, you could do this:

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data)
}
```

**EDIT**

Output in test.php:

put datefilter in a form

```
<form id="frm-test" action="test.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" id="dates" />
</form>
```

dates -> datefilter in test.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['datefilter'])) {
    $range = $_POST['datefilter'];
    echo $range;
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: This is what i am stuck on, i know it's sends so why is my test.php unable to detect and echo it?

Comment: Change alert( "success") -> alert(data) and tell me what value has the alert

Comment: It is "echoing". The "echo" is the response. If you remove the echo in the php file, you will not receive a response. If you are expecting this to print to the screen, it will not happen with your current setup.

Comment: is it possible to get the dates to output in test.php?

Comment: Of course, if you do not use ajax, look at the edition of the answer